# Is J2me peer to peer networking possible?

Tags: java, networking, java-me, network-programming

can two j2me wireless devices (cellphones)  directly communicate with each other over internet using  gprs ?

I have heard that these devices change their IPs fast and use dynamic NAT ...
Is it possible that the two device connect to each other using their  ip addresses .. Without using dedicated server in between them

Comment: considering the battery life, i don't think this is practical. at least not for the current technology.

Comment: Its look like you haven't used a gprs enabled cellphone yet

Comment: without any hub server, they have to keep pinging others to keep the address updated. tell me how this not drain the battery more then just browsing webpages.

Comment: If the ip keeps changing how could they update each other?

Comment: that's the point. You have to update other after you change ip and before other chanages -- that is, very frequently. That's why I say this drain too much battery.

Comment: Hmm... brilliant idea. But the situation is not that bad my phone can run for hours using gprs running messengers like nimbuzz , e buddy that need pinging to notify that u r online.. May be they wont ping that frequent

Answer (score 0):

I know only one telecom operator that allows a fixed IP to a phone: Nextel. It is based on Motorola iDEN technology. And to enable it you have to sign an specific service.